# How can i center my tikzpicture despite changing the scale?

Tags: tikz-pgf, center, scale

i recently started using Tikz and i can't solve this problem despite looking similiar problems up. I i try to scale my picture from 1 to 1.2 or higher the centering doesnt work.
I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance!!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{80}{45}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{-90}{180}{-90}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering

 \tikzset{surface/.style={draw=blue!70!black, fill=blue!40!white, fill opacity=.6}}

 \newcommand{\coneback}[4][]{
 \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=#2, #1] (45-#4:#3) arc (45-#4:225+#4:#3) -- (O) --cycle;
 }
 \newcommand{\conefront}[4][]{
 \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=#2, #1] (45-#4:#3) arc (45-#4:-135+#4:#3) -- (O) --cycle;
 }
 \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords, grid/.style={help lines,blue!40!white,opacity=0.2},scale=1.2]
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
   \fill[blue!40!white,opacity=0.5] (-4,-4,0) -- (-4,4,0) -- (4,4,0) -- (4,-4,0) -- cycle;
  
   \foreach \x in {-4,...,4}
     \foreach \y in {-4,...,4}
     {
         \draw[grid] (\x,-4) -- (\x,4);
         \draw[grid] (-4,\y) -- (4,\y);
     }
   \coneback[surface]{-3}{2}{-12}
   \conefront[surface]{-3}{2}{-12}
   \draw[->] (-4,0,0) -- (4,0,0) {};
   \draw[->] (0,-4,0) -- (0,4,0) {};
   \coneback[surface]{3}{2}{12}
   \draw[-,dashed] (0,0,-2.65) -- (0,0,2.65) node[above] {};
   \draw[-,dashed] (0,0,-4) -- (0,0,-3.35) node[above] {};
   \draw[->,dashed] (0,0,3.35) -- (0,0,4) node[above] {$time$};
   \conefront[surface]{3}{2}{12}
   \fill (4,0,2) circle (2pt) node[above right] {$C$};
   \fill (0,0,0) circle (2pt) {};
   \fill (-0.5,-0.85,2.2) circle (2pt) node[above left] {$A$};
   \fill (1.3,0.5,2) circle (2pt) node[above left] {$B$};
   \draw[->,red] (0,0,0) -- (4,0,2) node[below, pos=0.6, rotate=26.5651,scale=0.75,black] {$\textbf{spacelike vector}$};
   \draw[->,red] (0,0,0) -- (1.3,0.5,2) node[below, pos=0.6, rotate=55.1459,scale=0.75,black] {$\textbf{lightlike vector}$};
   \draw[->,red] (0,0,0) -- (-0.5,-0.85,2.2) node[above, pos=0.57, rotate=-65.8557,scale=0.75,black] {$\textbf{timelike vector}$};
   \node[black] at (0,0,3) {$Future\,\,Light\,\,Cone$};
   \node[black] at (0,0,-3) {$Past\,\,Light\,\,Cone$};
   \node[black] at (0,0.05,0.3) {$O$};
   \node[black] at (0,4.7,0) {$space$};
   \node[black] at (5,-0.3,0) {$space$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \caption{Light Cone in 2d Space plus a Time Dimension}
 \label{cone}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please write a minimal working example. See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means.

Comment: Your code does not compile. When you post a question, always provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Comment: [Wlcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436) I've added code to make your snippet compile, please provide complete code in the future. What do you mean by "centering does not work"? Changing the `scale=­`  option in your `tikzpicture` environment works as expected. Perhaps your document margins are causing a problem?

Answer (score 1):

The centering does work. You didn't specify the margin's size in your document, so when you scale your picture, LaTeX tries to center it, but the diagram cannot go onto the left margin. Obviously, you don't want your picture to be wider than the page itself. Therefore I believe that you need to do three things:

1. Decide the page size and text width.
2. Decide which part of the text width you want your picture takes up.
3. Scale it accordingly.

This all is about personal taste, but I like when my picture's width is the golden ratio of the text width.

I added these lines in the preamble of your code:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
a4paper,
total={170mm,257mm},
left=20mm,
top=20mm,
}
```

This is what I got:
[image]

If `\centering` line is removed, then, expectedly, we have:
[image]

In short, your issue in not with tikz package, but with your page geometry and picture positioning on the page. Some decisions are to be made on your side here. The rest works smoothly.